# how to split a string based on value in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, push

Is there a way to seperate a string into an array based on value? For example if I have a string `"1119994444455"` how would I turn that into `[111, 999,44444,55]`? I've attempted doing this but my method doesn't seem to be working.

my code:

```
var nums = [];

for(i in input){
    i = parseInt(i);

    if(i - beforeI != 0 && beforeI >= 0){
        insertionIndex++;
    }

    nums[insertionIndex] += i.toString();
    console.log(nums[insertionIndex]);

    var beforeI = i
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use a Regular Expression, like this

```
console.log("1119994444455".match(/(\d)\1*/g));
// [ '111', '999', '44444', '55' ]
```

Here, `(\d)` captures a number and `\1*` matches zero or more occurrences of the same captured number. The `g` at the end makes sure we don't stop after finding the first such match.